# Brackets json configuration file modification for PHP support

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

I am trying to use PHP Support in Brackets. My OS and configuration are as below;

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS
Brackets version: 1.14 build 1.14.1-17752
Bitnami LAMP Stack 8.0.2-0 installed for PHP, Apache Web Server, and MySQL database.
Bitnami install location: /opt/lampstack-8.0.2-0

On this system, I am trying to modify 'brackets.json' file to enable PHP support followed by the guideline mentioned [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/PHP-Support-in-Brackets).

And my json code is as follows;

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "themes.theme": "dark-theme",
    "useTabChar": false,
},
        "php": {"enablePhpTooling": true,
        "executablePath": "/opt/lampstack-8.0.2-0/php/bin/php",
         "memoryLimit": "4095M",
            "validateOnType": "false"},
```

I double-checked every `,` and `{}` but formatting seems fine. However, Brackets keep shows me this message.

> Your Preferences file is not valid JSON. The file will be opened so that you can correct the format. You will need to restart Brackets for the changes to take effect.

Is there any advice to change the configuration code? Thank you very much for spending time and attention to my question.

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ (or search for any `json validator`) for help with finding problems in your JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind comment. I will look for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```json
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "themes.theme": "dark-theme",
    "useTabChar": false,
    "php": {
        "enablePhpTooling": true,
        "executablePath": "/opt/lampstack-8.0.2-0/php/bin/php",
        "memoryLimit": "4095M",
        "validateOnType": "false"
    }
}
```

Think of JSON as a Javascript object hierarchy, with a *single* object (or array) at the root. So if you follow the opening `{` to its balanced closing `}`, that should be the end of the file. But in your example above, the closing `}` is immediately followed by `,` and then the "php" bit on the next lines – which makes it not valid JSON.

Comment: Oh my god... thank you so much!!! Your code perfectly works for me XD
I thought I already commented your answer but seems like I missed it. Thank you so much again!